# Should you use the parent if you are using the spring platform bom?

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot

Some dependency versions are not in so I've added the spring platform BOM, is the `parent` declaration still useful?

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.spring.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>platform-bom</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: I think that this is fine, if you're not working on a professional project. If it's meant to be professional level then you wouldn't want to have the spring-bom as your parent -- you'd have your own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally prefer to use `platform-bom` as a parent, i.e.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>io.spring.platform</groupId>
    <artifactId>platform-bom</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

In this way I don't have to define spring-boot version number and it is automatically updated with newer version of spring platform and I don't have to worry about any inconsistencies.

See http://docs.spring.io/platform/docs/1.1.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#appendix-dependency-versions for complete list of all managed dependencies.

**EDIT**: As pointed out by Andy Wilkinson, spring platform inherits `spring-boot-starter-parent` so all "sensible defaults" as described in http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-maven apply as well.

Comment: It's also worth noting that `platform-bom` inherits from `spring-boot-starter-parent` so, by using `platform-bom` as your parent, you also inherit Boot's plugin management, etc.

Answer (score 3):

There is a important difference between importing a BOM (in the `dependencyManagement` section) and using a `parent`

The BOM imported in `dependencyManagement` only provides defaults for dependencies, but a Parent-way include the other sections too (`plugins`, `plugin-managent`, `dependencies`, `dependencyManagement`...)

So when you remove the parent `spring-boot-starter-parent` then you have to copy the the `plugin-managent` stuff you need first.

Comment: interesting :) I guess you are referring to http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-maven

Comment: @sodik: no special reference, just maven knowege